# multiple string replace in php

Tags: php, string

php

```
$nn="ab bc cd cd ab";
$tttt=str_ireplace("cd","aaa",$nn);
$tt=str_ireplace("ab","aaa",$tttt);
```

but the below coding is not working

```
$nn="ab bc cd cd ab";
$tttt=str_ireplace("cd" or "ab","aaa",$nn);
```

The output is "aaa bc aaa aaa aaa".PLease help me in simplyfying it.because there are lot more str replaces for various words.

Comment: Use an array with `foreach`.

Comment: Look up `preg_replace`

Comment: You have a question in **PHP** about the function **str_ireplace**, so why don't you simply look into the manual? -> http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php <- Answer is there

Comment: Is this some kind of homework/school project? Other user: http://stackoverflow.com/q/31895327/3933332 but very similar coding style, variable names and writing style.

Answer (score 1):

You use array in first parameter of `str_ireplace`.

```
$nn="ab bc cd cd ab";
$replace_words = array("ab", "cd");
$tttt = str_ireplace($replace_words, "aaa", $nn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `preg_replace` which accepts regex as the first argument. `ab|cd` would match `ab` or `cd`.

```
preg_replace('~cd|ab~i', 'aaa', $nn);
```

And add `i` modifier for doing case-insensitive match.

Comment: No need for a regex here, since the function also takes an array as argument. (But it would work too :)

Comment: Even the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-ireplace.php) agrees with me: *If you **don't need fancy replacing rules**, you **should generally use this function** instead of preg_replace() with the i modifier.* :]